# Generating tor controlport password

Tags: javascript, node.js, proxy, tor, node-http-proxy

I am using the `tor-request` node module and am having problems. I have followed all steps and directions I could find, Ive searched every site online and I've restarted my computer. I cant finish my project and really am struggling. I keep getting **Double Quote Error**. Id appreciate any help.

//started tor

`tor &`

I generated the password with `tor --hash-password "myPasswordHere" | tail -n 1`

```
//I also tried
tor --hash-password myPasswordHereWithOutQuotes
```

//torr file

ControlPort 9051

```
HashedControlPassword 16:7{{numbers that ^^ returned}}786C1
```

//index.js / tor-request

```
var TorControlPort = {
  password: "myPasswordHere", 
  host: 'localhost',
  port: 9051,
  ...
```

ERROR `Uncaught Error: Error communicating with Tor ControlPort
551 Invalid quoted string.  You need to put the password in double quotes.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a bug in the library.

I checked out the source [here](https://github.com/talmobi/tor-request/blob/master/index.js#L134) and it doesn't look like the library is quoting the password as it should.

Relevant code:

```
var commands = [
  'authenticate '+ password +'', // authenticate the connection
```

As you can see the password is not quoted.

A temporary workaround you should be able to use would be to convert your ascii password to hex which Tor will allow without quotes.  e.g `password` = `70617373776f7264`.

Comment: Thank you, For anyone who this may help. I used this to convert password. This solved the quote error but caused another with verifying new tor session. http://www.dirtymonday.net/key_convert.html

Comment: I filed a bug report on github with the developer so we'll see what they have to say.  Glad that worked for the initial problem at least.

Answer (score 1):

drew010 is correct. I've responded to the github issue and pushed a fix and updated the README to be more helpful.

Sadly I can't upvote or comment on drew010's reply since I don't have required reputation.

[EDIT]: (I'm the author of the tor-request module)

Comment: Thanks for the quick response!